# zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, zsh, path

After I installed `nvm` locally, it auto added paths to `.bash_profile` file. But my default terminal use `.zshrc` so I copied those path over.

Everytime I fire terminal after above change, terminal auto prompt below warning.

> zsh compinit: insecure directories, run compaudit for list. Ignore
>   insecure directories and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]?

When I run `compaudit`, it prints following:

> There are insecure directories: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
>   /usr/local/share/zsh

Following are the paths that I copied over:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

How should I deal with this error? I don't understand why it thinks it's insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed those below NPM paths, and it fixed the issue meanwhile.

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```